# How to access Content of a ComboBox.ItemElements?

Tags: c#, combobox, telerik, webaii

I'm stuck in accessing the Content of comboBox.ItemElements which is as `enter code here`highlighted below. I'm unable to figure out what is the probable reason.

[image]

If I copy the expression in debug view this is how it is:

```
  ((ArtOfTest.WebAii.Silverlight.UI.ContentControl)new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<Telerik.WebAii.Controls.Xaml.IRadComboBoxItem>(comboBox.ItemElements).Items[0]).Content 
    "Thickness"
```

Here is what I'm trying to do: `var itemContent = comboBox.ItemElements.Content`
Could anyone please suggest?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. You want to change the "Thickness" value ?

Comment: I just want to get the value of Content which is "Thickness"

Comment: It's hard to help you because I don't own telerik components. By the I think you missed a part in your code between ItemElements and Content, like .Items[0]